# What is it called: a card necklace?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

Look at the picture

[image: branded strap with ID card attached]

This is a string that is knotted a card at one end. The card could be a swiping card or ID card (like some reporters often wear around the neck when they are on duty, they will be allowed to get in if they have the card for example). It is **not a piece of jewellery**. I am not sure if I can use the word "**necklace**".

> [​necklace](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/necklace_1?q=necklace): a piece of jewellery consisting of a chain, string of
> beads, etc. worn around the neck
>
> a diamond necklace

**What is it called: a card necklace?**

Comment: The fabric band around the neck to hold a “swipe card”, “identity card” or “access card” is called a **lanyard** in my experience. I have worn one constantly for at least 10 years at work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is generally called a **lanyard**. According to Cambridge English Dictionary:

> *lanyard*
> a long piece of cord (= thick string), etc. worn around the neck, on which a security pass, ID card, key, etc. is hung

Comment: If you're not going to accept my attribution, please add your own.

Comment: @Laurel Don't change a quotation.